# Dns works, can ping, but cannot load web pages in browser

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Yesterday I changed routers, and my desktop computer started acting up.  I could ping websites, and nslookup was able to resolve names to addresses, but neither chrome, firefox, nor ie could load any webpages.  None of my other computers connected to the same wireless router have any problems.  I connect my desktop to the router through a cheap wifi dongle.  I did a wireshark capture of the browser request, and I have uploaded the pcap here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7AsPdhWc-SwbTV0bUJLQXo4UUE/edit?usp=sharing

One strange thing I noticed was the spamming of ssdp packets.  I am not super familiar with networking, but it seems that it is not a problem with the router, as dns works, and so does dhcp (the desktop is assigned an address correctly).  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So I see the A and the AAAA record request/response for google.com (frames 2-5). I see a handshake with you and google in frames 6-8 and then an SSL handshake in frames 9-10. I see some transactions with KRB (kpop), an HTTP get request in frame 18 and then it looks like there is confusion, maybe lost packets and some dup acks and then FINs start getting thrown around. I'm guessing this is where your session starts to die - I don't ever see that GET request replied to. Have you tested for packet loss?

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I would personally use WinMTR, it is a mix of ping and tracert. You'll be able to monitor ICMP out to your target. I would choose something on your ISP network, such as their primary DNS. Let it run for a while (1 hr or more).

Comment: I did as you said and here is the report generated. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7AsPdhWc-SweC1Uc1FIZ2E2Q1k/edit?usp=sharing.  I'm not sure if there's anything significant here.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like you need to reset your TCP/IP try the following in a command line:

`netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt`

[How to reset TCP/IP by using the NetShell utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357)

Comment: Why? If protocols on a higher layer than TCP/IP work (DNS for instance), why would you assume something is wrong with TCP/IP?

Comment: When all else fails hit it with a hammer, amirite?

Comment: Unfortunately, that requires a disruptive reboot.